# How can I setup a "open in JupyterHub" button in GitLab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, gitlab, jupyterhub

We are setting up a JupyterHub instance for my Company. I'd like to have a button "open in JupyterHub" in the GitLab page of every committed notebook in GitLab.

When clicked, the user would be transported to a running copy of the notebook in JupyterHub. It would be equivalent to a "Open in Collab" or "Open in Kaggle" button that some notebooks display:
[image: Open in Colab and Open in Kaggle buttons]

I believe it would a great way to allow collaboration.

Maybe the button can trigger a clone or update action to the user JupyterHub and start a kernel with it.

How can we implement it?

Comment: There is no first party feature for this. So, would a tampermonkey script or similar be an acceptable solution to this? Also, would you be using the builtin JupyterHub GitLab integration (launched with GitLab-managed k8s and OAuth integration) or your own separate self-managed JupyterHub instance?

Comment: @sytech it would a separate JupyterHub instance.

Comment: Have you checked out [binderhub](https://binderhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? it seems like this may be exactly what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are many third party extensions for this. Consider something directly from major sources or websites, like the lab itself. BinderHub is one I personally use in my own scripts. Or you could create a script to directly modify it.